# A single page wiki

Tags: php, web, wiki

Do there exist any single page wikis?  i.e. a single wiki.php that a user can log into and edit the text of knowing that there is revision history, the ability to roll back, and all the other benefits of wiki systems without the overhead of full system.  If it stores data in a local flat file, that's fine.

tiddlywiki and wikionastick don't do this because they must be edited locally *and* don't have revision history.

Comment: Revision histories, rollbacks, logins, etc... ARE the full system.

Comment: So you want a small, but complete, PHP wiki. Good luck!

Comment: I don't think this is a bad question. I'm curious to see if anyone knows of a small self-contained capability like this (even if not exactly what he's seeking). For example, CVS and SVN can run without a server component and while using a file-based DB. What would keep a wiki from utilizing a similar approach (even if more than one page)?

Comment: Take a look at this list - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_wiki_software#PHP-based

Comment: Maybe PmWiki? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PmWiki

Comment: There are a lot of small, complete PHP wikis (PmWiki is a good example).  I'm only asking if there are any that have all of the code in one page.  That doesn't seem too exotic a desire.  It would be very bad form to make a wiki site out of 200 such pages linking to each other, but frequently entire wikis are put up only as a way for three people to jointly edit one document -- something that could be better done by a one-page-wiki.  That's where tiddlywiki and wikionastick come from -- but they don't have revision history.

Comment: Try this one : http://tiddlywiki.com/

Comment: tiddlywiki has serverside elements.

Answer (score 2):

I know its an old question, but I like to use : http://lionwiki.0o.cz

Its dated, an probably better systems out there, but i like it. Its simple, and SVN can handle this :)